# Decode and Upload a mime part to amazon s3 via c# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mime-types

I have a MimePart object that I would like to decode and upload to my AWS s3 account, if I were to decode the object to file and then read from that files location to upload it works fine, like this

```
var mimePart = (attachment as MimePart);
// Decode to file
 using (var fileStream = new FileStream("c:\Temp", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                mimePart?.ContentObject.DecodeTo(fileStream);
            }

// Upload to S3
using (FileStream fileToUpload =
                new FileStream("C:\Temp\TheFile", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                fileTransferUtility.Upload(fileToUpload,
                                           "bucket-name", "key");
            }
```

But I want to put everything into one using statement and cant figure out how to get it to work, something like

```
using (FileStream fileToUpload = (FileStream)mimePart.ContentObject.Stream)
            {
                fileTransferUtility.Upload(fileToUpload,
                                           "bucket-name", "key");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Had to use a memory stream

```
using (MemoryStream fileToUpload = new MemoryStream())
            {
                mimePart?.ContentObject.DecodeTo(fileToUpload);
                fileTransferUtility.Upload(fileToUpload,
                                           "bucket", mimePart.FileName);
            }
```